# Сортировка модели по полю в связанной таблице (Laravel4)

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Ребята, выручайте, российское сообщество Ларавела, к сожалению, бессильно.
Есть две таблицы - `articles(id, text, category_id)` и `categories(id, name)`.
Модели:

```
 class Articles extends Eloquent
{
    protected $fillable = array('text', 'category_id');

    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Categories', 'category_id');
    }
}

    class Categories extends Eloquent
{
    public $table = 'categories';

}
```

Задача получить все статьи, отсортированные по полю name.

Вариант:

```
Articles::with('category')->orderBy('name')->paginate(10)->get()
```

не работает. Выручайте.

**UPD**
Пока что заработало только

```
Articles::with('category')
        ->join('categories', 'articles.category_id', '=', 'categories.id')
        ->orderBy('categories.name', 'DESC')
        ->get();
```

Но хочется как-то попрямее.

Comment: А где связи то ? Да и сам вопрос непонятно сформулирован :(

Answer (score 1):

Точно не уверен, но попробуй :)

```
Articles::with(array('category' => function($query) {
        $query->orderBy('name');
    }))
    ->get();
```

Comment: Пробовал уже, не работает.

Comment: @Ridzhi так ошибки, логи или еще что-то?

Comment: Никаких ошибок, просто не сортирует, записи выводятся по id.